# Intersection of two vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ and $G$ be vector subspaces: $F=\operatorname{Span}\{(0,1,0)\}$ and $G=\operatorname{Span}\{(1,1,1)\}$.

What is the intersection between $F$ and $G$? In other words, what is $F\cap G=?$

I thought it would be $\{0\}$ but WolframAlpha tells me otherwise. I try to find the intersection in the following way:

1. $a(0,1,0)=b(1,1,1)$
2. I get the following system.
   $a=0$
   $a=b$
   $0=b$
3. The result is
   $a=0$ and $b=0$. Thus, $0(0,1,0)=0(1,1,1)=\{0\}$.

It seems that I am wrong. Please correct me.

P.S. If $F=\operatorname{Span}\{(x,0,z)\}$ and $G=\operatorname{Span}\{(0,0,z)\}$, the intersection would be the $z$ axis that traverses the $xz$ plane of $F$ subspace. But I can't prove that the way I do with the system. How do I prove it?

Comment: Apart from sloppy notation in your conclusion, you're correct. What did WolframAlpha tell you?

Comment: Yeah. On the paper, I can write it better.
Wolframalpha told me : F∩G = {1}
Thus, F and G is direct sum, isn't it? Thank you.

Comment: I have another question. 
F=Span{(x,0,z)} and G=Span{(0,0,z)}, the intesection would be the z axis that traverses the xz plane of F subspace. But I can't prove that the way I do with the system. How do I prove it?

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but it seems likely that WolframAlpha didn't understand that your were asking about vector spaces at all; instead it found the intersection of the sets $F=\{0,1,0\}=\{0,1\}$ and $G=\{1,1,1\}=\{1\}$. If I see your input to WolframAlpha, I probably would be able to know for sure how it interpreted your question.

Comment: I entered (1,1,1) ∩(0,1,0). Given that they are points... it shouldn't give me any correct outuput... You are right.

Comment: WolframAlpha didn't even interpret them as points! Once it saw the intersection symbol, it assumed that you entered sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've already taken care of your first question in the comments. Here's an easy way to answer your second question: since $G\subseteq F$, it follows immediately that $F\cap G=G$. The reason for $G\subseteq F$: any element $\mathbf{v}\in G$ is of the form $\mathbf{v}=(0,0,z)$ for some $z\in\mathbb{R}$; but then $\mathbf{v}\in F$, because we can represent it as $\mathbf{v}=(0,0,z)=(x,0,z)$, where $x=0$.

A note about your notation in the second question. Although it's not really wrong, but it's very unlikely that you would be given something like $F=\operatorname{Span}\{(x,0,z)\}$. It's more likely that the same subspace would be described as
$$F=\operatorname{Span}\{(1,0,0),(0,0,1)\} \quad \text{or} \quad F=\{(x,0,z)\mid x,z\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
If $x$ and $z$ run over all reals, the set of all vectors of the form $(x,0,z)$ already describes a vector subspace, so there's no need to take its span. Again, it's not wrong at all to take its span, as it's a meaningful concept for any given set of vectors; but since
$$\operatorname{Span}\{(x,0,z)\mid x,z\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{(x,0,z)\mid x,z\in\mathbb{R}\},$$
it's redundant to say "Span" there, so it's unlikely that a textbook or an instructor would do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solves my question. I seem to be skipping my lessons on sets, subsets,etc. I do need to work on the notations as well. It's very confusing for me. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @Quin0729: You're welcome! If this answer your question, then maybe you could vote on the answer and accept it...

Comment: first time that I ever use stackexchange. I didn't really know about the voting :-) Sorry about that.

Comment: @Quin0729: No worries, there's a first time for everything. :-) Welcome to Math.SE, and I hope you'll find it very useful.